# Wii to Wii U account transfer but my wii was lost in a move

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

I have no idea what happened to my Wii months ago when I moved but I shrugged it off because I was planning to get a Wii U. I just ordered a wii u and wanted to know if anyone had any luck with nintendo support to reinstate your purchases on a new system without having the original wii console available. I have about a dozen VC purchases and a free copy of mario 64 from club nintendo.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feels more like a discussion forum style request than the question and answer style we have at Arqade. As such, it will likely be closed.

Comment: I've heard reports of people getting their lost 3DS's account transferred to a new one, after confirming ownership of the account with their details and recent purchases. However, as the Wii's account system is entirely different, this may not be possible there. You'll have to call Nintendo.

Answer (score 2):

You won't know unless you call Nintendo. They could answer this question prior to purchasing a Wii U.

Purchases are tied to the Wii in question. If you have the Wii's serial #, then there's a chance the purchases can be restored. I've once found myself with a bricked Wii due to a power surge, and Nintendo required the serial # of both the old and new Wii in order to do the transfer.

I was unable to find *any* information online about whether or not you need to have the Wii in question, nor can I find anything that says they no longer do this. In that regard I would give them a call and let them be the final answer.